# Document.Domain madness

Tags: javascript, refresh, cross-domain

I've spent probably a month researching the internet on this issue and have yet to find the answer to this. My code does the following (all Javascript).

Let's say I have a test.html on mydomain.com

1. Very first thing in head section i set document.domain = 'mydomain.com';
2. Then, dynamically create iframe, set src to "subdomain.mydomain.com/test2.html"
3. Append iframe to DOM
4. subdomain.mydomain.com/test2.html: very first thing in head section: document.domain = 'mydomain.com';
5. test2.html has on_dom_ready event that tries to communicate with parent via window.parent

Works in all browser. even in IE6! The only problem is: when I refresh the page in IE, I get the access denied error.

The only way I can get rid of this error is to wait 12 seconds before calling window.parent. Not even 5 seconds help, I literarely have to wait 12 seconds. It makes no sense to me.

Anyone has any experience with this?

Comment: Do you have this problem in IE7 and IE8, or just IE6?

Comment: IE 7 and IE6 both, didn't test on IE8

Comment: By refresh, you mean hitting F5, or clicking in the url area and hitting enter? These trigger 2 different "styles" of reload, one which will hit the cache 100%, the other which will check the server for last-modified times. If you're seeing the error only on refresh with F5, try refreshing by putting the cursor in the url window and hitting enter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the onload event in the parent frame isn't triggered yet and so the DOM isn't completely built.  Here's a kludge that will scan for a div at an interval until it is present, without blowing up:

```
var minmax_SCANDELAY= 500;
var minmax_scanner;

function minmax_scan() {
    if (!window.parent.document.getElementById('content')) return;
    window.clearInterval(minmax_scanner);

    //replace following function call with your own.
    doYourMagicHere();
}

minmax_scan();
minmax_scanner= window.setInterval(minmax_scan, minmax_SCANDELAY);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

This is kind of a usefull information. The interval is a good idea instead of a timeout, I had to wrap the window.parent condition into try/catch statement, because it was throwing permission denied errors at me. The biggest and strangest problem, however is, that it takes really 10 seconds for the window.parent to become available to the parent frame. I even changed my on_dom_ready events to on_loads just to be sure, nothign helped.

I would like to stress once again - this is not a case on the FIRST load of the page..only after a refresh. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Furtive's Answer helped me a lot! He was 100% correct on the fact that the onload event is indeed the issue. I've looked deeper into my code and I found, that before creating the the child iframe, I am lazy loading some scripts with below technique:

```
lazy_load: function(url,on_finish_function)
{
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = url;
    var done = false;

    var This = this;
    // Attach handlers for all browsers
    script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if ( !done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == "loaded" || this.readyState == "complete"))
        {
            done = true;
            on_finish_function.call(This,null);
            head.removeChild( script );
        }
    };
    head.appendChild(script);
},
```

The above function modifies the HEAD section of the document.
The child iframe gets spawned at on_finish from this lazy_load function.

My guess is, that the IE browsers get really scared of this and take 12 seconds to recover from the shock of having the document modified like this :) What can I do about this issue? Why does the IE take sooo long to recover from the lazy_load dom manipulation?

Comment: head.removeChild( script ); inside my onload event was causing the problem.

Problem solved!